# Computer won't recognize headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

I recently got a new laptop through school. The problem is, I can't get the 3.5mm headphone jack to work consistently.

When I plug in headphones, it continues to play sound through the laptop's speakers, and no sound comes through the headphones.

I have Google'd this problem, and tried every solution that I could find, including:

- Going into device manager and checking for new driver updates.

  - They're up to date
- Going into various audio settings and seeing if devices are disabled.

  - They aren't.
- Running Windows troubleshooters.

  - It tells me to plug my headphones in, even though they already are.
- Trying to use the headphones in different devices

  - They work, so it isn't the headphones
- Trying to use different headphones

  - Still doesn't work. I even tried using USB-C headphones, and they don't work either.
- Updating Windows

  - Unfortunately, this is the one option that I can't try. It's the school's laptop, and they have policies in place preventing updates.

By enabling and disabling the driver in Device Manager, I've managed to get it working temporarily, so I know that the jack(s) aren't just fubared. It quits working when I hibernate/shutdown though. And now, I can't get it working again by toggling the drivers exactly as I did before.

About half (not all) of my classmates with identical computers have the same issue.

Does anyone have a clue what else I can try?

---

Dell Latitude 5500, Windows 10 version 1903

Comment: It just randomly started working again following a restart, but from previous experience, I don't trust that it will remain working.

Comment: Is the laptop connected to the school domain?

Comment: @NiallUK Yes, but it's the same behavior regardless.

Comment: Are you able to click the sound icon in the bottom-right of the screen and select which output you'd like the computer to use?

Comment: @SamForbis Via which option? Right clicking gives Open Sound Settings, Open Volume Mixer, Spatial Sound, and Troubleshoot. Sound Settings gives a output device dropdown with "Speakers/Headphones" as the only option (currently selected). The Volume Mixer just shows the same combined "Speakers/Headphones" device, along with System Sounds, and a slot for my web browser.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see. I was wondering if the computer would list speakers and headphones as separate output devices but it sounds like that's not the case. Is the port a combination headphone/mic jack or is it just a headphone jack?

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with the 5400, 5500, line of Dell Laptops. They used a MaxxAudio driver which gives issues. Might want to check on the Dell forums.

Comment: It's a combo mic/headphone port. That's the only one it has.

Comment: @NatsuKage For some reason, I didn't even consider this being a model-specific issue. I'll give that a lookover when I have time. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you plug in the headphones when the laptop is off, then turn on the laptop, does it work?

Comment: @NiallUK Yes, actually, at least in the test I just did.

Comment: That's funny because on my Optiplex 2050, the headphone jack only works if something is plugged in before the PC is turned on. Maybe it's a group policy that's been put in place by your school?

Comment: @NiallUK If it works via hibernating as well, that's a feasible workaround for the time being. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hardware fault in the socket. They typically contain a switch which is actuated by the insertion of the plug. This switch is used to disconnect the speakers.

See [Phone connector - switch contacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Switch_contacts)

> The more recent pattern of one NC contact for each signal path, internally attached to the connector contact, stems from their use as headphone jacks. In many amplifiers and equipment containing them, such as electronic organs, a headphone jack is provided that disconnects the loudspeakers when in use.

---

You could test for hardware vs software issued by booting from a live Linux CD or USB stick and seeing if the problem is the same for a different operating system. This can be done with no effect on your existing operating system and with no need to install software. This might be difficult if the school has taken measures to prevent this kind of use.

As the school owns the laptop, they should be politely asked to sort out the problem.

Comment: Hardware would seem likely culprit if it was just me, but unless we got a mass shipment of bad laptops, it seems less likely with multiple affected devices.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Maybe a manufacturing defect?

Comment: I actually have VMWare installed with Ubuntu. Would that work to troubleshoot, or does that just defer to Windows?

Comment: And actually, hardware seems unlikely now that I think about it (unless something's really fubared) since the USB-C port has the same behavior. Someone lent me their USB-C headphones to test, and they didn't work either (separate port).

Comment: VMware relies on the host OS for hardware interactions. If the USB-C ports exhibit the same issue it is more likely a software issue. I'll leave this answer in place as it might help others with a similar problem who find this as a result of a search.

Comment: That's fair. Someone mentioned in the comments that this appears to be a known issue with this laptop. I'll need to look into that lead when I have time